# Byte order and bit shifting

Tags: cpu-architecture, endianness, bit-shift

I am running a little-endian device so I expect a `u16` would be stored in this way:

```
Number     Byte 1      Byte 2
-----------------------------------
hex(255)   0xFF (LSB), 0x00 (MSB)
bin(255)   0b11111111, 0b00000000
```

If I left shift this word by 8, shouldn't it drop all the set bits and make the resulting value 0? I know that it does not (rather it multiplies the original value by 2 on each shift). Why?

Comment: The endianness of the machine only matters when dealing with muti-byte integers in memory. If you're operating on an integer in a register (which you are when you shift) the endianness doesn't matter. The C abstract machine has integers with the most significant bits on the left.

Comment: The assembler, compiler or interpreter for your language will know about the endianness of your system, and treat the numbers the "correct" way. So the two bytes `0xff 0x00` in memory will result in the actual number `0x00ff`.